# Use AWS Go SDK with profile

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-sdk-go

Is it possible to use profile from aws config files (*.aws* and *configuration*) directly in Go app, without setting any environment variables, like AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG, AWS_PROFILE or any other environment variable containing plain text credentials?

```
region := "xxxxxx"
profile := "xxxxxx"

  sess, err := session.NewSessionWithOptions(session.Options{
    Config: aws.Config{Region: aws.String(region),
              CredentialsChainVerboseErrors: aws.Bool(true)},
    Profile: profile,
})
```

Response is this:

> *NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain
>
> caused by: EnvAccessKeyNotFound: failed to find credentials in the environment.
>
> SharedCredsLoad: failed to load profile, xxxxxxxxxx.
>
> EC2RoleRequestError: no EC2 instance role found
>
> caused by: RequestError: send request failed*

Answer (score 3):

AS per the documentation yes, you can provide `profile` while creating the session.

[Credential and config loading order](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/aws/session/)

> By default NewSession will only load credentials from the shared credentials file (~/.aws/credentials). If the AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG environment variable is set to a truthy value the Session will be created from the configuration values from the shared config (~/.aws/config) and shared credentials (~/.aws/credentials) files. Using the NewSessionWithOptions with SharedConfigState set to SharedConfigEnable will create the session as if the AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG environment variable was set.

> The Environment variables for credentials will have precedence over shared config even if SharedConfig is enabled. To override this behavior, and use shared config credentials instead specify the session.Options.Profile, (e.g. when using credential_source=Environment to assume a role).

```golang
 sess, err := session.NewSessionWithOptions(session.Options{
      Profile: "myProfile",
  })
```

sample code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3"
)

func main() {
    region := "eu-central-1"
    profile := "myprofile"

    sess, err := session.NewSessionWithOptions(session.Options{
        Config: aws.Config{Region: aws.String(region),
            CredentialsChainVerboseErrors: aws.Bool(true)},
        Profile: profile,
    })
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    svc := s3.New(sess)
    _, err = svc.CreateBucket(&s3.CreateBucketInput{
        Bucket: aws.String("myxplbukcet"),
    })
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like it is either AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG has to be set, or SharedConfigEnable has to be set to true, but without them, providing profile is not sufficient to load info from aws config files.

Comment: this was missing: `SharedConfigState: session.SharedConfigEnable,`

Comment: @MatkoSoric above shared was working code, I didnt set any other variable.By default NewSession will only load credentials from the shared credentials file (~/.aws/credentials).Using the NewSessionWithOptions with SharedConfigState set to SharedConfigEnable will create the session as if the AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG environment variable was set

Comment: So your AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG is empty?

Comment: @MatkoSoric yes. Because I have credentials inside `~/.aws/credentials` and that is the default location for the SDK to look for.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Go is trying to use the shared credentials file but it's not able to find the appropriate profile. Can you check on your credentials file and look at the profiles available?

Comment: config files are fine, and profiles present